# Android WebView only redraws left side of page

Tags: android, webview

I'm replacing my original question because I found more info that I think makes the issue much clearer.

My XML is simple now, just a WebView that fills entire activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Web"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</WebView>
```

My full Java code is very simple now too:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(id.Web);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        String html = ""
                +"<!DOCTYPE html>"
                +"<html><head>"
                +"</head>"
                +"<body>"
                +"<div>"
                +"Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. "
                +"Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. "
                +"Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. "
                +"Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. "
                +"Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. "
                +"Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. Wide image below this text. "
                +"</div>"
                +"<div><img src=\"http://ampcocontracting.com/wp-content/uploads/ampco-collage-banner_about-us2.jpg\"></div>"
                +"<div>"
                +"Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. "
                +"Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. "
                +"Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. "
                +"Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. "
                +"Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. "
                +"Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. "
                +"Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. "
                +"Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. Wide image above this text. "
                +"<br>THE END!"
                +"</div>"
                +"</body>"
                +"</html>"
                +"";

        web.loadData(html,"text/html","UTF-8");
    }
}
```

The image in the HTML is a very wide image, just an example I found online, but any wide image has the same effect (in my real app/code I have to load HTML emails so I have little control over the actual HTML/content).

When I pinch to zoom in, or use the "+" native UI button, only the part of the page that is the "far left side" gets redrawn, everything "off the right side of the screen" doesn't get redrawn which produces this horrible looking skewed/sliced effect on the image and text.  When I zoom in, the screen doesn't stay scrolled to the left, so it is very obvious.  If I scroll the screen all the way to the left, it looks good/correct because that side got redrawn, if I scroll back to the right at all, it looks bad again.  Not just a temporary issue because I can continue to scroll around all over the page and it stays like that.  Zooming back out, or sometimes zooming in more, does sometimes "fix" it, but then zooming again will break it again.

I would just submit a bug and not post a question here, because it seems like an obvious bug, but I'm not seeing the same when viewing that HTML in the web browsers installed on the device (including built-in "Browser" and Chrome), and GMail and Yahoo Mail also don't have this issue.  I haven't seen any other reports of it online either, so I hope there is a simple answer or work-around that is so obvious nobody else has even asked, but has managed to escape me...?

**If I zoom in/out and scroll around enough I can get it looking this bad, which is why I don't think I can "just live with it":**

[image: super bad]

**Here is how it should look, and does when first loaded:**

[image: good]

**If I do nothing but pinch to zoom a small amount, it looks like this if I scroll to the left after this, the part that is visible looks good, but scrolling back to the right I can still see this messed up part):**

[image: bad]

Comment: Are you manually setting the zoom factors, or letting the WebView take care of it? Can you also provide the API level of the device you're seeing this on?

Comment: API 17, Android 4.2.1, letting the WebView take care of it, ASUS Transformer Pad TF300T, but I don't see this issue in the browsers (including Chrome) I have installed or GMail, so don't think it is an outright bug with just this device (otherwise I'd test on others and move on).

Comment: I was able to recreate with a subset of code/xml and figured out more details so I pretty much replaced the original question with a better one.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Maybe Resposiveness?

Comment: @eselk have you tried setting `setUseWideViewPort(true)` in your WebView's settings?

Comment: @Abhi, I don't doubt that the content/HTML could be modified to avoid the issue, making it mobile-responsive or who knows what, but in the end I need to support "almost any content", and would expect it would look/work as well (the same) as the native browser.  I've never seen this issue in the native browser though, so hard for me to just tell users "Android has a bug".

Comment: @loadedion I tried that just now and it does seem to fix the issue.  The text no longer auto-wraps/resizes, but I might be able to live with that.  I had tried before, but with my full code-base, not this simple version, and think I found some reasons that wouldn't work well.  I'll have to retest and maybe this is my "fix".  Still curious why this issue exists in the first place, if anyone has more details (i.e.-Google docs/blog saying you have to use this mode if using wide images?) and wants to post as answer, that would be great.

Comment: @loadedion thanks a ton, I think this will end up being my fix.  Feel free to post that as an answer so I can accept if nobody comes along with more info/better answers.  I think the reason I couldn't use that setting easily is because in my real code I'm also trying to add a header to the HTML with TO/CC/SUBJECT info and it was messing up the look/layout when using setUseWideViewPort(true), but at least that is unique to me (not SO friendly) and not something a web browser does, so I can find another way to handle that.  This "obvious bug" was just driving me crazy.

Comment: Glad to help. It's odd that adding the header within the HTML would cause issues though, as the content within the WebView should be irrelevant as far as the view container is concerned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `setUseWideViewPort(true)` in your WebView's settings

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MarsAtomic to be fair I did ask him to post this as an answer, since it did resolve the issue.  I'd love it if someone could explain why, with lots of details and other options, but as it stands I'm pretty happy to at least have a work-around, and it's possible the best/only answer is "it's just a bug, Android is full of them, this is the work-around most people use" :)

Comment: the issue what i am facing is setUseWideViewPort(true)  is making the page center of the page with small font , any solution for this?